# org-babel: can the plot size be specified?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, code

I was wondering if the output plots resulting from `org-babel` blocks are customizable in size (how they appear in the `org-mode` buffer, as in its dimensions X and Y). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For controlling image size in org-mode, you can use:

```
#+attr_org: :width 300px
```

in the newest version of org mode, percentage is allowed:

```
#+attr_org: :width 50%
```

Comment: Thanks, and where shall I include  this line? after "#+begin_src R" or before "#:results"? Not clear. Thanks.

Comment: Also, how to set both height and width? Can't find height anywhere in the org manual.

Comment: You will want to name your code blocks (with `#+name: foo`) in order for this to work for repeated evaluations. Otherwise, you will get new `#+results` sections and you will have to add the `#+attr` section (and delete the old crud) again and again.

Comment: You are only able to set the width: the height is changed automatically keeping the aspect ratio of the image constant.

Comment: @NickD, Can you give an example? So the #+name comes first and below the #+begin_src R babel line?

Comment: That's correct: then the `#+RESULTS` block should be named as well with the same name. Subsequent evaluations will reuse that named results block, even if you add `#+attr:` lines before the results block. If you don't use named blocks, you'll get a *new* results block because the `#+attr:` line would make the old result block unreachable from the code block.