# Changing dimensions of plot in orgmode: #+attr_org: :width 160px

Tags: org-mode, inline-image, format

When wanting to change a plot in Orgmode with `#+attr_org: :width 160px`.
Is there a way to individually specify height as well such as `#+attr_org: :weight 160px :height: 300px`? This does not set the height. I couldn't find a way.
Thanks!

Comment: You mean `width`. And I already commented on that in your earlier  [question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/70652/org-babel-can-the-plot-size-be-specified).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [org-babel: can the plot size be specified?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/70652/org-babel-can-the-plot-size-be-specified)

Comment: Yes, I corrected it (width)!

Comment: I was hoping that the height can be set too, but seems it is now. Am I correct?